# Computer can not see any bootable USB devices

Tags: windows, boot, bios, bootable-media

I have a computer, where Windows got corrupted. At this point there are two SSD's in it that are both formatted. So no more Windows.

I would like to install Windows on it, but I can't get it to boot from a USB flash drive. Ideally this would be fixed. I have tried five different USB flash drives, with both Windows and Linux. My MacBook Pro, however, can see the USB flash drive.

Here is how my BIOS is configured:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Note that in the last screen with the “UEFI Samsung Disks” this is with Linux on the SSD).

If I need to make any change, or need to provide more information then please let me know.

**UPDATE**: I formatted a USB flash now with the "Windows Media Creation Tool", my MacBook Pro can see them fine.

[image]

My Windows computer can not, I changed the BIOS to this:

[image]

Advanced:

[image]

Those are the settings used with rufus:

[image]

Comment: If you are unable to see disks, it means they are not configured to support UEFI, as indicated by your second screenshot.  At this point there is no reason why you shouldn't use UEFI.  You will have to investigate the reason your Windows installation media doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: In addition to what @Ramhound said, did you use the "windows 10 media creation tool" to create your Windows 10 boot media?  I myself have found that tools like rufus don't properly handle UEFI.. this might be my own stupidity but I am just sharing.  You can enable legacy vs UEFI or do as Ramhound suggest which is fix your installation media (the better choice probably).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Ok, I did use "windows 10 media creation tool" now. I still can not see the usb. I did change "Boot from Storage Devices" to "Both, UEFI first".

Comment: Bummer dude.. :( .. I have also had this problem but using the media creation tool fixed it.  Hopefully some genius will come along that knows more than I do. :) .. good luck!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm unsure what sort of issues you've had with Rufus, but it's supported UEFI USB creation for ~5yrs, if not longer, and does so without issue.

Comment: @clankill3r Use the media creation tool to save as an ISO, then use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create the bootable USB. CSM mode must be disabled and should never be enabled _(UEFI is a 64bit firmware and CSM mode emulates BIOS' 16bit acrchitecture, whose purpose was solely to support distros 5+ yrs ago that didn't support UEFI boot)_. The option in your last screenshot is regarding storage controller option ROMs, which has nothing to do with booting _(OpROMs are the firmware settings for storage controllers that come with an OpROM)_

Comment: What are your computer model and BIOS version? What happened that caused you to format the disks?

Comment: Did you set your UEFI to enable USB (in `advanced`) at all?

Comment: 1. Can update your question with your motherboard model?
2. Have you tried disabling Secure Boot or changing it to another option which I guess is `Other OS`? Here is some other suggestions directly from ASUS:
https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1030858

Comment: Try resetting your BIOS settings to "Optimized defaults", Save and reboot. Then use the F8 and F12 keys at POST to open the "BBS boot selection" menu which should allow you to select the boot device for one boot. Let me know if you can see the USB drive from that menu.

Comment: What FS is the UFD formatted with? If NTFS, you might try to backup the Windows setup files of the UFD, repartition/format it with a single FAT32 partion and copy the files back to the UFD.

Comment: You shouldnt have to change your bios to select a different boot device, you can normally make use of a "Boot menu". On asus motherboards, you can normally use the F8 key at boot to enter this menu else check your manual.

Comment: @7heo.tk I can't find that, I added a screenshot for the Advanced as well in case it helps.

Comment: Probably is under the `USB Configuration` section :) Could you check in there? (and possibly make a screenshot, that'd be great)

Comment: @gregg It's ASUS Maximus V Extreme motherboard. I tried disabling secure boot. I will check the link now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while back when installing Ubuntu since Windows just didn't want to detect the USB drive. Try using `MiniTool Partition Wizard`. You can find it on this website https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html
Try using it to wipe the partition on your USB and then format the USB for NTFS also try using balenaEtcher to put the windows iso onto the USB.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the setting "Secure Boot" is enabled on your bios. This setting is probably blocking your capability to boot from the flash disk.

Check the page 61 of [this manual](https://dlsvr04.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/STRIX_Z270F_GAMING/E12350_Z270F_GAMING_BIOS_EM_WEB.pdf) for a similar motherboard.

Also, when creating bootable flash disks always check if you are creating them for UEFI or BIOS boot, I recommend using [rufus](https://rufus.ie) for this kind of drive creation. This can affect the windows installation, requiring extra steps

Comment: Should it be UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Also I tried `Secure Boot` with both `Other OS` and `Windows UEFI mode` but it still won't boot.

Comment: I added a screenshot with rufus settings in the OP.

Comment: If you are using the UEFI setting on rufus you can disable CSM. CSM is a module that provides compatibility to BIOS boot devices.

I had a similar problem on my mother board, when using CSM I couldn't find the second nvme ssd as a bootable device.